# Using over() in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table Employees:

[image]

How can i get the maximum of sum salaries by departments, use over() (without subqueries, cte) ?

I need a result, like that:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the question is about multiple levels of aggregation, rather than `over()` (analytic/window functions) specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle 12C, you can do:

```
select department_id, sum(salary) as sum_salary
from t
group by department_id
order by sum(salary) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

I cannot readily think of another way of handling this without a subquery or CTE somewhere.

I should note that Oracle has this strange way of nesting aggregations, so you could get the maximum salary without a subquery:

```
select max(sum(salary)) as sum_salary
from t
group by department_id;
```

EDIT:

Okay, I thought about it a little more.  You can do this without subqueries or CTEs:

```
select max(department_id) keep (dense_rank first order by sum(salary) desc),
       max(sum(salary)) as sum_salary
from t
group by department_id;
```

I am loath to recommend using the "nested" aggregation functions.  Such queries are much easier to follow when the aggregations are nested.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak . . . I laugh.  I thought I originally wrote "loath" and it corrected me.